# My computer logs out and sleeps after two or three songs play on itunes

Tags: itunes, mac, sleep-wake, user-account

Recently I did some updating on my computer just to make the display better, change sleep length (extended, not shortened), and to add hot corners.

Well, now when we play up to two or three songs on iTunes, the computer logs the user out with no warning. I've gone to different timing settings, but I can't seem to find the problem.

Anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 1):

Open `System Preferences`→`Security & Privacy`, unlock the padlock if it's locked, and then in the `Privacy` pane click on the `Advanced...` button. See if you've enabled "Log out after [x] minutes of inactivity".